# How can I change the database settings in openx-2.6.4?

Tags: database, configuration, openx

I just transferred open x to a new server and need to change the db info (host, username, password, db name). I have been looking over and I can't find a settings, config file.

Update: Found config file inside var folder

Answer (score 17):

Config file is found inside the `var` folder in the OpenX root folder.